# im suddenly having this error in shopify Failed to connect to name.myshopify.com port 443: Connection refused what is the issue?

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app

Failed to connect to name.myshopify.com port 443: Connection refused when using API, I get this error.
is this an issue by hosting server or is there any setting in Shopify I need to change?

Comment: If you have an issue with a third party service, please start by contacting the service provider. We're not their support and can't see if there's anything strange/needed on your account.

Comment: its my own custom app im using in a development store. it was working fine than suddenly im getting this error

Comment: Sure, but the issue is with Shopify's API, which is a third party service so again, you should contact them and ask why them why _their_ service all of the sudden start returning "connection refused". Neither we (or you) have any clue what could have happened on their side. It could be something wrong with the account, or some issue with their servers. That's something only they can answer so always start by contacting the service provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution
basically i need to allow Shopify store IP in firewall on our App server